# Determining image height & width in order to scale and size other elements in proportion?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How would one determine the width and height of an image loaded using `d3` in order to:

1. Scale it proportionally
2. Size other elements (like a border) to the image

This is for an `Electron` project so I am using `path` in my code, etc. In the image below and the code which produced it, I have an image I scale to an arbitrary size – and I would like to size the `rect` with the green border to fit the image.

It seems that the aspect ratio of the image is preserved if just one dimension is provided, so #2 above is the most important question I have.

---

**Updated Answer**
Extending #ccprog's answer to include selecting the sibling in the `on load` callback:

```
newEvent.append("image")
    .attr("class", "event-content")
    .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
    .attr("y", 15)
    .attr("width", 160)
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
        return path.join(__dirname, "assets", "image_01.jpg")
    })
    .on("load", function (d, i) {
        var rect = d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll("rect")
        var h = this.getBBox().height;
        rect.attr("height", h);
    });
```

### [image]

**Image snippet**

```
  newEvent.append("image")
                .attr("class", "event-content")
                .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
                .attr("y", 15)
                .attr("width", 160)
                // .attr("height", 120)
                .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
                    return path.join(__dirname, "assets", "image_01.jpg")
                })
```

---

**Full code**

```
var events = content.selectAll("g").data(data.filter(function (d, i) {
                return i < data.length - 1
            }));

            var newEvent = events.enter()
                .append("g")
                //   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_content.left + "," + 0 + ")")
                .attr("class", "event");

            newEvent.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "event-content")
                .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
                .attr("y", 15)
                .attr("width", 160)
                .attr("height", 120);

            newEvent.append("circle")
                .attr("class", "event-circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("cx", horizontal_margin)
                .attr("cy", 0)
                .on("click", eventClick);


            newEvent.append("image")
                .attr("class", "event-content")
                .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
                .attr("y", 15)
                .attr("width", 160)
                // .attr("height", 120)
                .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
                    return path.join(__dirname, "assets", "image_01.jpg")
                })



            newEvent.append("text")
                .attr('y', 5)
                .attr("x", horizontal_margin + 15)
                .attr("class", "event-text")
                .text(function (d) {
                    var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%B %e, %Y")
                    var dateStr = formatDate(d.date)
                    return dateStr;

                    // return d.eventText
                });
```

Comment: You are relying on a new feature of SVG2 (still in development) where SVGImage will be able to have an *auto* size. Currently only chrome does support this. SVGImage doesn't expose any info about its content, so to know what you need to know, you'd have to load the image in an HTMLImageElement in parallel (should be cached), and to grab its `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`. Ps: an other alternative would be to read the Media's binary content and extract these info directly (might be faster, but harder to implement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point here is that you have to wait for the image being loaded before you can get at its dimensions. Only then you can compute the `rect` height.

While Interface HTMLElement provides properties `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`, SVGImageElement does not. You have to first render the image, and grab its bounding box with `SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()`.

```
        var rect = newEvent.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "event-content")
            .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("width", 160);

        newEvent.append("image")
            .attr("class", "event-content")
            .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("width", 160)
            .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
                return path.join(__dirname, "assets", "image_01.jpg")
            })
            .on("load", function () {
              rect.attr("height", this.getBBox().height);
            })
```

Comment: In svg1.1 (still the version is use  in all UAs except chrome), you must set both `width` and `height` attribute for your SVGImageElement to load. And calling `getBBox()` will only outputs the values you entered as attributes, not the real size of the loaded media.

Comment: @Kaiido What you said doesn't seem to be correct. Have a look at this fiddle, at no moment I set the `height` of the image. Yet, the images load and the `getBBox` gets the correct height: https://jsfiddle.net/njmr23mv/ . Am I missing something?

Comment: And at no moment your images load on current FF nor any other browser than chrome.

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, that's correct, it's not working on FF, only Chrome. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: But anyway, getting the BBox is just similar to the answer below, it's in no way the size of the loaded media, but just the one of the container (a bit like `HTMLImageElement.width`, except that it's always overridden. The only ways for OP to get the real dimensions, are to load it through an HTMLImageElement or to read the File's content ;-)

Comment: But it seems to me that OP doesn't want the real height of the image, just the scaled height. And, for that, `getBBox` works. The problem, however, as you pointed ou, is that OP cannot simply set the width and let the browser resizing the image accordingly.

Comment: And so would `getBoundingClientRect`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Had to wrangle accessing the sibling differently (`var rect = d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll("rect")`) – but it seems to work ok.

Answer (score -1):

I think [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) should do the trick for you.

```
var image_d3 = newEvent.append("image")
            .attr("class", "event-content")
            .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("width", 160)
            // .attr("height", 120)
            .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
                return path.join(__dirname, "assets", "image_01.jpg")
            })

 var img_rectange = image_d3.node().getBoundingClientRect()
 // you'll now have be able to read from img_rectange.height or img_rectange.width
```

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` returns the size in screen coordinates. If a parent element of the image contains some transformation, the numbers might differ from the local coordinate system inside the `<g>` element the image + rect sit in.

Comment: In addition, at the point you are reading it, the image is not yet loaded and the height will be 0.